# Stack-AVL transfer algorithm

Tags: algorithm, analysis

Pretend I have an algorithm that pops every element from a stack and inserts them into an AVL tree.

```
If pop () is a O (1) method and insert () is an O(log n) method,  
my algorithm is O(log n), O (n) or O(n log n)?
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your algorithm is `O(nlogn)`, or `Theta(nlogn)` to be exact**, assuming insert is `Theta(logn)`.

The `i` step cost `c1 + c2*log(i)` (`c1` the constant of `pop()`, `c2` is the constant guaranteed for AVL insertion), so you get:

```
c1 + c2*log(1) + c1 + c2*log(2) + .... + c1 + c2*log(n) = 
= c1*n + c2*log(1*2*...*n) = c1*n + c2*log(n!) <= (for large enough n) (c2+1)*log(n!)
```

If we "ignore" the constants its much more readable (less accurate of course, and must be done carefully, but it's good for intuition):

```
log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n) = log(1*2*...*n) = log(n!)
and log(n!) is in O(nlogn)
```

It is known that `log(n!)` is in `Theta(nlogn)` - and thus this is your total complexity.